# How to Run an app as Administrator without the prompt?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, uac, prompt, ssms

When I start SQL Server Management Studio 2008, I get an error that's been around forever and is documented [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d5d3e5fc-d8ce-4f42-b7ea-9bbbb7756a20).  One of the suggestions to fix it that actually worked was to start SSMS with Run as Administrator.

So I modified the properties of the shortcut to always run it as the administrator.  The only annoyance is that I get a prompt every single time asking whether I really want to do it.

Is there a way to tell just this one program (SSMS) to not pop up the prompt, while keeping this behavior for other apps?

Comment: This is e very good question. I vote UP :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Read the following forum post: [How to disable the User Account Control Prompt for certain application](https://web.archive.org/web/20161025074728/http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/117680-disable-uac-prompt-certain-applications.html)

It tells you basically, that you have to download **Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.6** and create a custom App fix database where you assign the 'RunAsAdmin' fix to the exe. I tried it and <del>it worked for me</del> *I thought it worked.*

---

**Another way**

... is described in
[How to Create a Elevated Program Shortcut without a UAC Prompt](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html)

This solution requires you to create a 'scheduled' task for the application and running the app means triggering the task. (For a detailed description with screenshots see the link):

- Run the *Task Scheduler* via `taskschd.msc` and *Create Task...*

  1. Tab *General*: Give the name `[Name]` to the new task, check *Run with highest privileges* and choose "Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2" from the dropdown list *Configure for*
  2. Tab *Actions*: Add *New...* Action *Start a program* with *Program/script* = `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe` and *Add arguments* = `/c start "[Name]" "C:\Program Files\Sample\Program.exe"`. Substitute `[Name]` with the name of the task (step 1) and the fill in the path to the program which should run elevated.
  3. Tab *Conditions*: Uncheck *Stop if the computer switches to battery power* first, and then uncheck *Start the task only if the computer is on AC power*
- Create a new shortcut oh the desktop or wherever with the following target *location*

  ```
  schtasks /run /tn "[Name]"
  ```

  Once again, `[Name]` is the name of the task (step 1)!
  *Run* as *Minimized* if you don't want the command window to flash up.
- This shortcut and task can only be created and work while logged in as an administrator account.
  It'll not work in a standard user account.

Comment: Also see the following answer on Arcade.se http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42747/11789

Comment: f3lix's answer (2nd part) works for me. I believe this should be accepted answer.

Comment: I was able to open an application without UAC Prompt using Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit 5.6. However, I can't seem to create a shortcut *to the added database.* What this means is I have to launch the application within the "MS-Toolkit" via **Run** and I don't see how that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.  If such a thing were possible, every piece of malware would set that option, which would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: It is possible. Take a look f3lix's answer.

Comment: @DRAX It still does require the administrator prompt; it just requires it at a different time. I.e. you have to be an administrator to create the scheduled task. If you're an administrator, then save yourself some time and just run the application directly as an administrator. The correct solution is to have the program's author fix it so that it doesn't require being an administrator (because there'a very little chance that  it actually needs administrative access).

Comment: @Ian OP asked for a workaround while he had administrator access. If you have different issue (like not being administrator) you should search other questions or open new one. BTW, I am pretty sure that most applications require administrator access for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Solution **WITHOUT** creating shortcuts:

You can download the *Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit* (just download it from [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352)).

Once the toolkit is installed, the rest of the instructions are more complex, but they are very well detailed and explained in the link http://meridian.ws/wordpress/?p=306

This solution is good for skipping the prompt when opening files that are associated to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Scheduled Tasks.

Create a new Scheduled Task to start your program. *You must create the task as the user who will run the program*, or the user may not be able to see the task.

Once created, change the credentials used for the task to be a user with administrator privileges. You must also set the task to `Run whether user is logged on or not`, and to `Run with highest privileges`. Make sure not to check the `Do not store password.` option. The administrator account you use must also have the [`Log on as a Service` privilege](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ablock/archive/2008/09/18/setting-the-properties-the-log-on-as-a-service-and-allow-log-on-locally.aspx) in the Local Security policy.

Additionally, in the `Settings` section there are several default options that don't make sense for a task of this type. For example, you probably don't want to kill the task just because the user left the program idle for a few days.

You can then create a shortcut to the task for the user.

Comment: Note that this is distinct from the other suggestion to use a scheduled task because it doesn't require routing through `cmd.exe`, but does require the user account that will run task to create it originally.

Answer (score 0):

just locate the main exe icon and right click then go to properties and switch to "compatibility" tab and press " change settings to all users, then finally mark on " run this program as administrator" and voila !!! the application wont ask anymore for permissions :D

Comment: This is not working. What Windows Edition & it's Version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You can't set this up for a single application. All you can do is turn off UAC altogether - which is not recommended. If you stop and consider it for a second, you're actually better off clicking a "yes" button once in a while, compared to a malware taking over your computer.